# How make Accordion to sliding next steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to run this Accordion so that when you fill in the input and click the button to close the previous step and move on to the next step ...
and also to click the previous button to close the active step and go to the previous step.

I tried to put it together somehow but after clicking there was no action

Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
var accordion = (function() {

  var $accordion = $('.loanForm-js');
  var $accordion_header = $accordion.find('.loanForm-header-js');
  var $accordion_item = $('.loanForm-item-js');

  // default settings
  var settings = {
    // animation speed
    speed: 400,
    // close all other accordion items if true
    oneOpen: false
  };

  return {
    // pass configurable object literal
    init: function($settings) {
      $accordion_header.on('click', function() {
        accordion.toggle($(this));
      });
      $.extend(settings, $settings);
      // ensure only one accordion is active if oneOpen is true
      if (settings.oneOpen && $('.loanForm-item-js.active').length > 1) {
        $('.loanForm-item-js.active:not(:first)').removeClass('active');
      }
      // reveal the active accordion bodies
      $('.loanForm-item-js.active').find('> .loanForm-body-js').show();
    },

    toggle: function($this) {
      if (settings.oneOpen && $this[0] != $this.closest('.loanForm-js').find('> .loanForm-item-js.active > .loanForm-header-js')[0]) {
        $this.closest('.loanForm-js')
          .find('> .loanForm-item-js')
          .removeClass('active')
          .find('.loanForm-body-js')
          .slideUp()
      }
      // show/hide the clicked accordion item
      $this.closest('.loanForm-item-js').toggleClass('active');
      $this.next().stop().slideToggle(settings.speed);

    }
  }
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  accordion.init({
    speed: 300,
    oneOpen: true
  });
});
```

```css
.loanForm-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.loanForm-form-content {
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
}

.loanForm-details-content {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.loanForm-position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.loanForm-position-fixed {
  width: 330px;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 100;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.loanForm-details-box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background: orange;
}

.loanForm-details-info {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.loanForm {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

.loanForm-header,
.loanForm-body {
  background: white;
}

.loanForm-header {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  background: #fdd365;
  color: #353353;
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
  font-size: .7em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.loanForm-item .loanForm-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}


/*.loanForm-item.active .loanForm-header:hover {
  background: #2D3D99;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.loanForm-header:hover {
  background: #2D3D99;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
 */

.loanForm-body {
  background: #F9F9FF;
  color: #353353;
  display: none;
}

.loanForm-form {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.loanForm-item.active:last-child .loanForm-header {
  border-radius: none;
}

.loanForm:first-child>.loanForm-item>.loanForm-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.icon::after {
  display: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.loanForm-item>.loanForm-header::after {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .3s all;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}

.fa-f077,
.fa-f078 {
  float: right;
}


/*
chevron up: f077;
chevron down: f078;
 */

.loanForm-item.active>.loanForm-header::after {
  content: "\f077";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.loanForm-item.active .loanForm-header {
  background: #FF4C60;
  color: #F9F9FF;
}

.loanForm-item.activated .loanForm-header {
  background: #9de3d0;
  color: #353353;
}

.loanForm-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dabd44;
}

.loanForm-item.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.loanForm-item.activated {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #85c9b6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <div class="loanForm loanForm-js">

    <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js active">
      <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Create Account</div>
      <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
        <div class="loanForm-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group text-right">
            <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
      <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Personal information</div>
      <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
        <div class="loanForm-form">
          FORM INPUT HERE
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
      <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Adress</div>
      <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
        <div class="loanForm-form">
          FORM INPUT HERE
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
      <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Employment and income</div>
      <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
        <div class="loanForm-form">
          FORM INPUT HERE
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
      <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Documents and Consents</div>
      <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
        <div class="loanForm-form">
          FORM INPUT HERE
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
      <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Summarization</div>
      <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
        <div class="loanForm-form">
          FORM INPUT HERE
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
              <button type="button" class="loanForm-send btn btn-default">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to add jquery in your snippet to perform the actions..

Comment: **@ManirajMurugan**  hello sorry but I'm new to JS

Comment: @Syntaxeen you can get links to jquery at [https://code.jquery.com/](https://code.jquery.com/) . Insert the link in the head of your document and you'll be fine. Your code works when jquery is added to the snippet. Yay! :)

Comment: @RachelGallen hello, I have jquery.min.js in html and this Accordion works for me but I need to achieve that when I click the button next, it goes from step 1 to step 2 and every time you click the back button, the active step closes and goes to the previous step.

Comment: @Syntaxeen I note you don't have anything on click of the buttons; toggle show/hide on click? It's kind of overkill though imho, going next in an accordion is intuitive

Comment: @RachelGallen I need it because of a multi-step form ...

And yes I don't have anything on the buttons; show / hide on click

because I don't know how to do it :) And sorry for my English but I'm Slovak and translate via google translator

Comment: Look up show() and hide functions in jQuery. I'm about to eat now. There's lots on stackoverflow about toggle visibility on click. Your English is fine!

Comment: @RachelGallen I've tried different options on $ ('. LoanForm-next'). Click (etc ...
but nothing helped so I turned here

Comment: @Syntaxeen, Added answer below, please check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.. You need to include two functions for `next` and `prev` button click and need to find the closest next and previous element using,

For **next** element with class `loanForm-item-js`

```
$(this).closest('.loanForm-item-js').nextAll('.loanForm-item-js:first')
```

For **previous** element with class `loanForm-item-js`

```
$(this).closest('.loanForm-item-js').prevAll('.loanForm-item-js:first')
```

Added two functions for next and prev click respectively like,

```
$('.loanForm-next').on('click', function() { ... })

$('.loanForm-prev').on('click', function() { ... })
```

Working snippet as follows,

```js
var accordion = (function() {

  var $accordion = $('.loanForm-js');
  var $accordion_header = $accordion.find('.loanForm-header-js');
  var $accordion_item = $('.loanForm-item-js');

  // default settings
  var settings = {
    // animation speed
    speed: 400,
    // close all other accordion items if true
    oneOpen: false
  };

  return {
    // pass configurable object literal
    init: function($settings) {
      $accordion_header.on('click', function() {
        accordion.toggle($(this));
      });
      
      $('.loanForm-next').on('click', function() {
        // accordion.toggle($(this));
        $(this).closest('.loanForm-js')
          .find('> .loanForm-item-js')
          .removeClass('active')
          .find('.loanForm-body-js')
          .slideUp()
        $(this).closest('.loanForm-item-js').nextAll('.loanForm-item-js:first').toggleClass('active')
        console.log();
        $(this).closest('.loanForm-item-js').nextAll('.loanForm-item-js:first').find('.loanForm-body-js').stop().slideToggle(settings.speed);
      });
      
      $('.loanForm-prev').on('click', function() {
        // accordion.toggle($(this));
        $(this).closest('.loanForm-js')
          .find('> .loanForm-item-js')
          .removeClass('active')
          .find('.loanForm-body-js')
          .slideUp()
        $(this).closest('.loanForm-item-js').prevAll('.loanForm-item-js:first').toggleClass('active')
        $(this).closest('.loanForm-item-js').prevAll('.loanForm-item-js:first').find('.loanForm-body-js').stop().slideToggle(settings.speed);
      });
      
      $.extend(settings, $settings);
      // ensure only one accordion is active if oneOpen is true
      if (settings.oneOpen && $('.loanForm-item-js.active').length > 1) {
        $('.loanForm-item-js.active:not(:first)').removeClass('active');
      }
      // reveal the active accordion bodies
      $('.loanForm-item-js.active').find('> .loanForm-body-js').show();
    },

    toggle: function($this) {
      if (settings.oneOpen && $this[0] != $this.closest('.loanForm-js').find('> .loanForm-item-js.active > .loanForm-header-js')[0]) {
        $this.closest('.loanForm-js')
          .find('> .loanForm-item-js')
          .removeClass('active')
          .find('.loanForm-body-js')
          .slideUp()
      }

      $this.closest('.loanForm-item-js').toggleClass('active');
      console.log($this.next());
      $this.next().stop().slideToggle(settings.speed);

    }
  }
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  accordion.init({
    speed: 300,
    oneOpen: true
  });
});
```

```css
.loanForm-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.loanForm-form-content {
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
}

.loanForm-details-content {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.loanForm-position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.loanForm-position-fixed {
  width: 330px;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 100;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.loanForm-details-box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background: orange;
}

.loanForm-details-info {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.loanForm {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

.loanForm-header,
.loanForm-body {
  background: white;
}

.loanForm-header {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  background: #fdd365;
  color: #353353;
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
  font-size: .7em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.loanForm-item .loanForm-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}


/*.loanForm-item.active .loanForm-header:hover {
  background: #2D3D99;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.loanForm-header:hover {
  background: #2D3D99;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
 */

.loanForm-body {
  background: #F9F9FF;
  color: #353353;
  display: none;
}

.loanForm-form {
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.loanForm-item.active:last-child .loanForm-header {
  border-radius: none;
}

.loanForm:first-child>.loanForm-item>.loanForm-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.icon::after {
  display: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.loanForm-item>.loanForm-header::after {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .3s all;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}

.fa-f077,
.fa-f078 {
  float: right;
}


/*
chevron up: f077;
chevron down: f078;
 */

.loanForm-item.active>.loanForm-header::after {
  content: "\f077";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.loanForm-item.active .loanForm-header {
  background: #FF4C60;
  color: #F9F9FF;
}

.loanForm-item.activated .loanForm-header {
  background: #9de3d0;
  color: #353353;
}

.loanForm-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dabd44;
}

.loanForm-item.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.loanForm-item.activated {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #85c9b6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form action="#">
                        <div class="loanForm loanForm-js">

                            <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js active">
                                <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Create Account</div>
                                <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
                                    <div class="loanForm-form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label for="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group text-right">
                                            <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
                                <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Personal information</div>
                                <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
                                    <div class="loanForm-form">
                                        FORM INPUT HERE
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
                                <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Adress</div>
                                <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
                                    <div class="loanForm-form">
                                        FORM INPUT HERE
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
                                <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Employment and income</div>
                                <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
                                    <div class="loanForm-form">
                                        FORM INPUT HERE
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
                                <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Documents and Consents</div>
                                <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
                                    <div class="loanForm-form">
                                        FORM INPUT HERE
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-next btn btn-default">Next</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="loanForm-item loanForm-item-js">
                                <div class="icon loanForm-header loanForm-header-js">Summarization</div>
                                <div class="loanForm-body loanForm-body-js">
                                    <div class="loanForm-form">
                                        FORM INPUT HERE
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-prev btn btn-default">Prev</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-right">
                                                <button type="button" class="loanForm-send btn btn-default">Send</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

> [**Working codepen here...**](https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/jOPBZpb)

Comment: I have three css definitions:
loanForm-header-js <- background: yellow
loanForm-header-js.active <- background: red
loanForm-header-js.activated <-background: green

if I wanted to implement colors for steps?

Comment: @Syntaxeen, I am unable to get you what you want to achieve in css??

Comment: @Syntaxeen, Also it is something extra you are asking out of question.. Feel free to accept the solution if it solves your issue as per the question..

Comment: Ok i make new Question